# How to call a static property within the initializer of a subclass in Swift?

Tags: swift, initialization, subclass, static-methods, static-members

I have created an extension on `NSManagedObject` to return an entity name equal to the object's concrete class name, possibly the name of a subclass:

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    static var entityName: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

}
```

I expect that this property returns the string "Coffee" for a subclass defined as follows:

```
class Coffee: NSManagedObject { ... }
```

Now I also want to define a custom initializer on `NSManagedObject` which uses the property `entityName` defined above.

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let entityName = Self.entityName //  How to obtain the entity here?
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: context) else {
            fatalError("Could not find entity with name \(entityName)")
        }
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    }

}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access the static `entityName` here. Obviously, I cannot refer to it as `NSManagedObject.entityName` as this would execute the superclass' implementation which would return "NSManagedObject" rather than "Coffee". `Self` doesn't work either because it's not a protocol.

#### So how can I call the static property on the actual subclass from within this initializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type(of: self)` so you can access the entity name

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

        let entityName = type(of: self).entityName //  How to obtain the entity here?
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: context) else {
            fatalError("Could not find entity with name \(entityName)")
        }
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot call an instance property of an object before initializing it.

Comment: Oh sorry i missed that i am updating my answer

Comment: Thanks, but more precisely: You cannot access `self` before `self` has been initialized.

Comment: you can use in type of

Comment: OMG, I didn't know that! Thank you! (It's a little inconsistent in my opinion, but I'm happy it works... )

Comment: yes see this for more detail: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type